# Flag Records Sharing fieldA value where FieldB value null for all

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that has a fieldA that multiple records can share.

I have another field, Value.

I have a third field, GroupLeaderFlag that flag based on some prior relationships which records that share fieldA is the core record in that group so I can do further comparisons with the value and other fields between them.

In some cases I have NOT been able to flag GroupLeaderFlag for a given group based on the prior relationships.

So I'd like to do a secondary process to flag GroupLeaderFlag with the following rules:

- The records share the fieldA ID
- None of the records with that fieldA ID has a GroupLeaderFlag i.e. all of those records that share fieldA are NULL
- The record in the groups that meet that criteria with the lowest Value (there are cases where two or more could share the lowest value but it is rare)

UPDATE:
I realize I have another field GroupLeaderName where for each fieldA group I store the Name/ID of the record I determined/flagged for that group as GroupLeaderFlag so that I have that Name/ID handy per record in the group.

So this becomes another field to group by to get the fieldA groups that did not end up with a GroupLeader.

I successfully ran a Select, but cannot turn it into an Update:

```
Select fieldA,Name,Min(Value),'X' 
as GroupLeaderFlag from TableA 
where GroupLeaderName is NULL  
group by fieldA
```

So basically I need to turn this into an Update so that the output I get from the select which is the name of the record in the fieldA group which has no GroupLeaderFlag and the lowest value in that group along with a temp field with value 'X' into an update.

UPDATE: I discovered that the each fieldA group is naturally ordered by value asc, relieving me of the need to extract the lowest value per groupin. So I did this:

```
Update TableA as T1
Inner Join
(Select ID,GroupLeaderFlag from TableA 
group by fieldA having Count(GroupLeaderFlag )=0) as T2
On T1.ID=T2.ID set T1.GroupLeaderFlag ='X'
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

1. The column `Name` is unique (or at least within the same `fieldA`)
2. The flag column is either a `'X'` (looking at your example) or `''` (empty string) -- although I prefer a `0` or `1` value

This query will return the names of the new group leaders:

```
SELECT 
    fieldA,
    (SELECT Name FROM MyTable s 
     WHERE s.fieldA = n.fieldA 
     ORDER BY `Value` LIMIT 1) AS `Name`
FROM MyTable n 
GROUP BY fieldA 
HAVING MAX(GroupLeaderFlag) = ''
```

Combining that in an `UPDATE` will result into

```
UPDATE MyTable u
JOIN (
  SELECT 
      fieldA,
      (SELECT Name FROM MyTable s 
       WHERE s.fieldA = n.fieldA 
       ORDER BY `Value` LIMIT 1) AS `Name`
  FROM MyTable n 
  GROUP BY fieldA 
  HAVING MAX(GroupLeaderFlag) = ''
) AS f USING (fieldA)
SET GroupLeaderFlag = IF(u.`Name` = f.`Name`, 'X', ''),
GroupLeaderName = f.`Name`;
```

Proof of concept: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9be4b/1

Comment: Wow. One issue is that no Name is not unique but I will use that as a foundation. The Name select in fact is not such critical just a) the fieldA grouping and b) the min value.